# realURL language switching for alias based pages?

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have an issue regarding realURL alias page switch. I have a custom module for products, for each product i have URL in both available languages (de & en). But when i switch to language then it doesn't take me to the same page i was on.

For Example:
product page For German language is /de/produkte/product-details/gewindeschieber-typ-g4/ and if i switch it to english language then it should switched to english url(/en/produkte/product-details/threaded-slide-gate-type-g4/) of same product. But it goes to /en/produkte/product-details/

Please let me know How to fix this issue ?

Comment: did your language menu configured with typoscript or you used any extension for language menu?

Comment: @GhanshyamGohel Yes, i have create language menu with typoscript.

Comment: ok thanks, let me know your url params for detail page like for news "tx_news_pi1[news]=1" or "tx_product_ext1[uid]=1" ?

Comment: Ok, see this link [link](http://abs-armaturen.net/de/referenzdetails/dammbalkenverschluss-typ-d2i/) , at top right you can see language switch, when you switch to english then it go back to its main page not one its english counter part [link](http://abs-armaturen.net/en/reference-details/stop-log-system-type-d2i/)

Answer (score 1):

You have two languages German DE and English UK.
Supposed your lang menu TS looks like:

```
lib.languageMenu = HMENU
lib.languageMenu {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,1

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="lang">|</ul>
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      linkWrap = <li>|</li> || <li>|</li>
        #parameter.insertData = 1
      stdWrap.override = <img alt="de" src="fileadmin/flags/Flag_Germany.png" width="35"/> || <img alt="uk" src="fileadmin/flags/Flag_United-Kingdom.png" width="35"/>
      #stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    }

    ACT < .NO
    ACT {
        ATagParams =  ||  ||
      #doNotLinkIt = 1
      linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li> || <li class="active">|</li>
    }
    CUR < .NO
    CUR {
       ATagParams = || ||
      #doNotLinkIt = 1
      linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li> || <li class="active">|</li>
    }

    # NO + Translation doesn't exist
    #USERDEF1 < .NO
    #USERDEF1.doNotLinkIt = 1

    # ACT + Translation doesn't exist
    #USERDEF2 < .ACT
    #USERDEF2.doNotLinkIt = 1
  }
}
```

> 0 = German [de] and 1 = English [en]

Now you need to append your detail page params to the lang menu TS: eg. tx_news

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
    lib.languageMenu.1.NO{
        additionalParams.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        additionalParams.intval = 1
        additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[news]=|
    }
[global]
```

- tx_ [prefix]
- <your_extension_key>_
- <your_fe_plugin_key>_
- [<variable_name>]=
- <value>

In you case may be your params "tx_referenzen_<fekey>[uid]=<detail-referenzen-uid>" You have to check in your typo3conf/realurl_autoconf.php

Comment: Perfect !! Thousand likes to your comment. It worked..
I have a small issue of realURL now.. why this [link](http://abs-armaturen.net/referenzen/) opens home page, it should open [link](http://abs-armaturen.net/de/referenzen/)

Comment: You gave link that doesn't have "de" or "en" params, or either you have to skip de params coz German is default language : 'preVars' => array ('1' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'en' => '1'
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            )),

Comment: Yeah Sure !!  i voted your answere it will show when i will be have 50 reputations.

Comment: @Ghanashyam , Can you help me on solr search [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348879/keep-getting-runtimeexception-error-while-indexing-pages-in-solr-search-in-typo3)